# Selenium Grid v.3.1.0 Test - Unable to create new remote session

Tags: firefox, jenkins, selenium-grid, geckodriver

I'm trying to launch **Firefox (v. 51.0.1), Chrome (v. 56.0.2924.87)**, Edge (v.38.14393.0.0)** and Opera (v. 43.0) ** on a different machine (Windows 10) by using Selenium Grid.
**It's working well with Chrome browser** but always getting some issues with the remaining browsers. 
Please see the following error message :

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=WIN10}], 
required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: ..., os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-62-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

My command to launch the Remote browser (for example Firefox 51.0.1):

**java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0.jar -role node -hub http://[jenkins.mydomain]:4444/grid/register -browser platform=WIN10,browserName=firefox,version=51.0.1**

My testcode on Eclipse (just an simple example):

```
package testpackage; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class FirefoxJenkins {
    RemoteWebDriver driver;
    @Parameters({ "platform", "browser", "url", "version" })
    @Test
    public void FirefoxTest() throws MalformedURLException{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\DEV\\geckodriver.exe");
    //RemoteWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    caps.setBrowserName("firefox");
    caps.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WIN10);

    //FirefoxProfile profile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile("default");
    //profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(false);
    //profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
    //caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://[jenkins.mydomain]:4444/wd/hub"), caps);
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.de");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.quit();
    }


}
```

XML- file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--Set thread-count = 3 to execute test parallel in 3 max browsers at at time. You can increase it-->
<suite name="Parallel Tests" verbose="1" thread-count="1" parallel="tests">
 <tests>
  <test name="Windows+firefox Test">
   <parameters>
    <parameter name="platform" value="WIN10"/>
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
    <parameter name="url" value="http://www.google.de/"/>
    <parameter name="version" value="51.0.1"/>
   </parameters>
   <classes>
    <class name="testpackage.FirefoxJenkins"/>
   </classes>
  </test> 
   </tests>
</suite>
```

*(Same codes with other browsers)*

I've already tried out several things but it didn't work out for example:

- command java: -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\DEV\geckodriver.exe"-jar selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0.jar -role node -hub http://[jenkins.mydomain]:4444/grid/register -browser platform=WIN10,browserName=firefox,version=51.0.1

PS: I have the same problem by trying to launch edge and opera (even by using  with IEDriverServer.exe and operadriver.exe).

Could you please help me on this issue? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do. For some strange reason I have noticed that at times Selenium Webdriver gobbles away the actual exception and instead gives you that generic exception which I agree is difficult to de-cipher.

So you can do the following (The actual line number may vary depending upon the Selenium version. I am assuming that you are using the Selenium 3.0 binaries )

You need to setup a breakpoint in `org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake#createSession(org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient, java.lang.StringBuilder)` [Selenium 3.2.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.2.0/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/ProtocolHandshake.java#L98-L123) , [Selenium 3.1.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.1.0/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/ProtocolHandshake.java#L98-L123) on this line

`String resultString = response.getContentString();`

and run your test in debug mode. The actual response value of `resultString` should tell you the real problem.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I've already tried it out  but got the same error. I couldn't really figure out what the value of `resultString` is but the failure exception is always telling me that there is something wrong with this line :  `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://[jenkins.mydomain]:4444/wd/hub"), caps); ` And it's still working by using chrome. Do you have any other suggestion ? I appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please try once again with Selenium 3.3.1 ? With this version you don't need any breakpoints etc., and the error should be evident

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and help. Now it's working with Chrome and Firefox as well but still getting the same error by trying to launch edge and opera: `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities`

Comment: Are you sure that your Grid/Node is also running on 3.3.1 ? There was a bug fix that I pushed in and which got merged, that fixes the problem of relaying back the error back to the test. But this needs 3.3.1 to be used at both the client (your tests) and the server (grid hub and node) end.

Comment: Yes, both are running on 3.3.1 (server as well as client) but still getting the same error.Is it possible that this is still a general issue ? Cause I've found that bug right here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10088793/  But if you've already pushed a bug fix in than I guess it's just my problem.